# How do you place namespace alias on an XElement? How do you add a datasource to existing RDL document?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, linq-to-xml, ssrs-2008, rdl

I am trying to create an XElement of a datasource to insert into an SSRS RDL file. However, I am unable to seem to get it to create correctly with respect to the rd: alias. Here is the code I am using.

```
XNamespace rootNs = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition";
XNamespace rdNs = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner";
XElement _dataSource = new XElement("DataSource",                            
             new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "rd", rdNs),
             new XAttribute("Name", "eFinancials_LOCAL"),
             new XElement("ConnectionProperties", new XElement("DataProvider", "SQL"), new XElement("ConnectString", connectionString)),
             new XElement(_rdns + "SecurityType", "DataBase"),
             new XElement(_rdns + "DataSourceID", dataSourceId)
                                            );
```

Resulting XML element is:

```
<DataSource xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" Name="eFinancials_LOCAL">
  <ConnectionProperties>
    <DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider>
    <ConnectString>Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=800_LMS_eFin_Deploy</ConnectString>
  </ConnectionProperties>
  <SecurityType xmlns="rd">DataBase</SecurityType>
  <DataSourceID xmlns="rd">56e5e869-6ca5-44f9-8340-22821177569e</DataSourceID>
</DataSource>
```

But, it needs to be:

```
<DataSource Name="eFinancials_LOCAL">
  <ConnectionProperties>
    <DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider>
    <ConnectString>Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=800_LMS_eFin_Deploy</ConnectString>
  </ConnectionProperties>
  <rd:SecurityType>DataBase</SecurityType>
  <rd:DataSourceID>56e5e869-6ca5-44f9-8340-22821177569e</DataSourceID>
</DataSource>
```

How can I adjust my code to create the correct XML as above? I almost to the point where I am just going to create it as text.

Comment: Doh.. never mind.... found a stupid but in my code.

Answer (score 2):

```
XNamespace ns = @"http://www.somesite.com/xml/customer/2006-10-31";
XElement xe = new XElement(ns + "customers", 
   new XAttribute("xmlns", ns),
   new XElement(ns + "customer", new XElement(ns + "firstname", customer.FirstName);
```